# How to link two java applets?

Tags: java, applet

I have a log-in form and a registration form as two separate applets in the same package. Problem is how can i link/connect these two applets so that i log-in form displayed after registering the details in the registration form and clicking on the submit button i can see the log-in form.

Comment: I think you should manage it that the whole app is one applet with different content.

Comment: *"one applet with different content."* CardLayout is excellent for that, though not the only way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comment that the best way to do this is probably to not have two applets. That being said, you could always communicate with javascript. Applets can run javascript on the webpage. This javascript call can be used to lookup and call methods on the other applet.